# Plotting a point cloud and moving the camera

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot, visualization

I have a list of points given by their x, y, z coordinates. I would like to plot these points on a computer. I have managed to do this with gnuplot and with the python library matplotlib separately. However for these two solutions, it seems hard to change the 'viewing point', or the point from which the projection of the 3D point cloud to the 2D screen is done.

1) Is there any easy way to, preferably continuously, move the viewing point in gnuplot (the splot command) or with matplotlib (the plot command)?

2) What other libraries are there for which this is an easy task?

EDIT: I want to *move* the viewing point (like the player in an first-person shooter, say), not change the viewing angles.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this with matplot3d.. example form site: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html.  Once you run plt.show() you can drag the perspective and then save.

Comment: @ryanmc : When I drag in those plots I only change the viewing angles, not the position of the viewing point. I have edited to clarify that I want the latter. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Based on your edit; I don't understand the difference between *"move the viewing point"* and *"change the viewing angles"*.

Comment: Or do you mean including e.g. zooming into the data?

Comment: @Bart : If we think of the computer screen as the screen of the camera, I am referring to moving or turning the camera respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, gnuplot cannot *really* move the viewing point, for the good reason that the viewing point is at infinity: all you can do is set an angle and magnification (using `set view`) and an offset within the viewing window (with `set origin`).  That means, you can move the viewing point on a sphere at infinity, but not among the points you're plotting.

(Question 2 is off-topic as a software advice, but you're looking for a rendering software such as paraview)

Comment: Thanks for the off-topic advice! (and the answer, of course) Worked out great for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the viewing angles it's like moving your head on an equidistant shell seeing continuously the center of the image/screen/object.

What you said is moving your head in the x-y plane looking fixedly ahead so the content (the screen/object) shifts out from your sight. It is easy in `Gnuplot` with `set origin` like

```
set origin -0.25,0
splot exp(-x**2)*exp(-y**2)*sin(x)**2 with pm3d notitle
```

[image]

simply shifts the camera.

[image]

What you have *mean* (I think) is step left (or right or jump or...) with your player but this changes not just the viewing point but also the viewed content. You can achieve it with `xrange` and `yrange`:

```
splot [-5:15] exp(-x**2)*exp(-y**2)*sin(x)**2 with pm3d notitle
```

[image]

Of course the changing of the x/y ranges depends on the current viewing angles what you have to calculate outside of `Gnuplot`.